# Include associated model's attributes in ActiveRecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, collections, associations

I'm trying to structure my list of blog posts in a way where each blog post object has all associated data. I need it structured like this because I'm handing the data off to my JavaScript front end.

I need a data structure with simple entries similar to this:

```
[
<BlogPost id: 12,
  image: "image.png",
  title: "corrupti",
  content: "\n## Fuga eveniet beatae necessitatibus excepturi c...",
  blog_author: {
    id: 8,
    name: "Theodan Wells"
  },
  blog_category: {
    id: 6,
    name: "Marketing"
  }>
]
```

The associations are probably obvious, but here are my models anyway:

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog_author, inverse_of: :blog_posts
  belongs_to :blog_category, inverse_of: :blog_posts
end

class BlogAuthor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blog_posts, inverse_of: :blog_author
end

class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blog_posts, inverse_of: :blog_category
end
```

I'm sure I need to use `includes` or `joins` and then somehow pluck the attributes to include them in the collection, but I'm just not sure how.

I know how to do this by manually forming the data structure with `collect` and `map`, but last time I used these methods it slowed down my server responses tenfold. Literally went from 8s to 0.8s when I took the collect statements out last time.

Comment: Yeah, use include to include it... also when you run `to_json` (I'm assuming you're passing it to your js frontend via json)  you will need to include it in that too. Have a google for how `to_json`/`as_json` work, to show how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by overriding the `as_json` method as below:

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog_author, inverse_of: :blog_posts
  belongs_to :blog_category, inverse_of: :blog_posts

  def as_json(options = {})
    if options[:index]
      {
          id: id,
          image: image,
          title: title,
          content: content,
          blog_author: {
                         id: blog_author.id,
                         name: blog_author.name
                       },
          blog_category: {
                         id: blog_category.id,
                         name: blog_category.name
                          }
      }
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Then call the **BlogPost** with `as_json` at the end, also add `includes` so it will get the data from the association in one go, as below:

```
BlogPost.includes(:blog_author,:blog_category).as_json(index: true)
```

**NB:**
In case you have a lot of fields in the association, then better to add `select` with `joins` to your query to choose the exact fields, as below:

```
    BlogPost.joins(:blog_author,:blog_category)
            .select("blog_posts.id,blog_posts.image,blog_posts.content ,blog_posts.title, blog_authors.id, blog_authors.name, blog_categories.id, blog_categories.name")
            .as_json(index: true)
```

Comment: This is a viable answer to get it done, but isn't this essentially doing the same thing as `collect` by just manually building the returned collection?

Comment: @Doug if you have lots of fields, `collect` and `map` won't be helpful as they deal with data returned from the server, instead you need to select the exact fields to avoid taking a long time fetching data from other fields.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing this up. I like this answer. Just did a test and the query is much quicker. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [deep_pluck](https://github.com/khiav223577/deep_pluck) if you have performance issues. It can pluck data without loading a bunch of records. Therefore being several times faster than using `as_json`

```
BlogPost.deep_pluck(
  :id, 
  :image, 
  :title, 
  :content,
  blog_author: [:id, :name],
  blog_category: [:id, :name],
)
```